# Decision variable in rhs of a constraint, implemented in R with lpSolveAPI or lpsolve

Tags: r, linear-programming, lpsolve

This is my first question on Stack Overflow.

I'm working on a optimization problem with **R** and the package `lpSolveAPI` which, to this point, works perfectly well for me.

**My problem is very simple: How do I add a decision variable to the right hand side of a constraint?**

Let `C1,C2,...,C50` be the decision variables. **How do I formulate a constraint like C1 > C34**?

This seems to be so easy, that I have the feeling that I'm missing the point somewhere, but every post I've read and every example I've seen works with constant numeric constraints like `C1 > 1000`.

I don't have much experience with LPs or MILPs, so maybe there is a clever way to reformulate the constraint so it works with a numeric value on the rhs?

An example constraint from my application looks like this:
`10 C1 + 2 C11 <= 200 C51`

Comment: `C1 >= C34` can be rewritten as `C1-C34 >= 0`. `10 C1 + 2 C11 <= 200 C51` can be rewritten as `10 C1 + 2 C11 - 200 C51<= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

right after posting this question, i've had an idea how to solve it and it is really easy as well:

10 C1 + 2 C11 <= 200 C51 ---> 10 C1 + 2 C11 -200 C51 <= 0

This way it fits into the solver API!